# How to rename file with a sequence that restarts if certain matches exist

Tags: python, batch-file, file-rename

That title doesn't explain much but I couldn't summarize it quickly.  Let's say I have files like this (all in the same directory)...

```
abc_foo_file1_morestuff.ext
abc_foo_file2_morestuff.ext
efg_goo_file1_morestuff.ext
jkl_zoo_file0_morestuff.ext
jkl_zoo_file1_morestuff.ext
jkl_zoo_file4_morestuff.ext
xyz_roo_file6_morestuff.ext
```

And I want them renamed to:

```
abc-1.ext
abc-2.ext
efg-1.ext
jkl-1.ext
jkl-2.ext
jkl-3.ext
xyz-1.ext
```

So basically some files in sets (abc, jkl, xyz) got removed and some got renamed to have a zero in them so they'd be listed first.  But I want to resequence them to start at 1 and not have any gaps in the sequence.

I tagged this with Python because that's what I've attempted before, but if there's a simpler or cleaner approach, I'm all for it!

Comment: So you want to rename the files, keeping the first three characters, then adding a `-`, then a number (starting from 1, not right-aligned with zeroes), then the old extension?

Comment: That's correct.  No padded-zeros needed in this instance, but I tried to write the question to be useful to otthers, so maybe somebody else finding this one day would be interested in that.

Comment: Is this name wrong?: `xyz-6.ext` I think it should be `xyz-1.ext`

Comment: 1. what is more important: using the first 3 characters, or everything before the first `_`? 2. does the sort order of the input files matter? (so `jkl_zoo_file0_morestuff.ext` *must* become `jkl-1.ext`, for instance?)

Comment: @Aacini - you're correct. I updated the question, thanks.

Comment: @aschipfl - What matters for segment1 is everything before the first underscore.  And yes, the sort order is very much what matters... whatever is the lowest number of the set should become #1.

Comment: Okay, so the sorting is a bit tricky, because `dir` sorts _strings_, not _numbers_, so numbers like `1`, `2`, `10` will be sorted like `1`, `10`, `2` by `dir`; so when realising your script as a [tag:batch-file], sorting needs to be done programmatically; so is the portion containing the sort number always there _after the 2nd `_`_, and is it always prefixed with the word `file`?

Comment: @aschipfl - yes the sorting number is always after the second underscore and always prefixed with the word file.  (sorry for my delays everybody)

Comment: Thanks for clarification; there is one thing left which is not clear to me: supposing there are two files `abc_AAA_file8_*.ext` and `abc_BBB_file5_*.ext`, how should they be sorted? should the part `AAA` or `BBB` be regarded for sorting, and if yes, should it take precedence over the index `8` or `5`?

Comment: @aschipfl - what you're asking would not happen in my setup.  the first segment is sort of an ID code, and the second is more like a human-readable ID code.  so they would remain paired identically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My general approach to this problem would be the following steps:

- Get a list of all of the files you want renamed
- Create a list of the starting sequences
- Go through a list of the files that start with each sequence changing their names
- Optionally, sort the list of files in each sequence

So, in python that would look like:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, splitext
import shutil
import re

mypath = "./somewhere/"

# this function taken from an answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort
def natural_sort_key(s, _nsre=re.compile('([0-9]+)')):
    return [int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower()
        for text in re.split(_nsre, s)]

# Get a list of all files in a directory
infiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]

# Create a set of starting sequences
sequences = {splitext(file)[0].split('_')[0] for file in infiles}

# Now go about changing the files
for seq in sequences:
    files = sorted([f for f in infiles if f.startswith(seq)],
                   key=natural_sort_key) # sort the files, if you like
    for idx, file in enumerate(files):
        new_name = seq + '-' + str(idx + 1) + '.' + splitext(file)[1][1:]
        print(file, " -> ", new_name)
        # copy or move
        #shutil.copy2(join(mypath,file), join(mypath,new_name))
        #shutil.move(join(mypath,file), join(mypath,new_name))
```

Comment: This also has the advantage of keeping everything around if you wanted to do some other sort of transformation on the filename, starting sequence or iteration index.

Comment: Updated to include natural sorting of filenames and splitting on the '_'.

Comment: Also, made creating the list of starting sequences and the filterable dictionary much more pythonic.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I was able to mold this a little more since, of course, the requirement is now different from what I initially asked.  And I'm sure it will change again several times before the day ends.  Such is the life of an underling.  But this works great and I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Process each EXT file in the specified directory.
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%A IN (`DIR /B /S "C:\Path\To\Files\*.ext"`) DO (

    REM Extract the prefix.
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1 delims=_" %%X IN ('%%~nA') DO SET Prefix=%%X

    REM Running tally of each prefix.
    SET /A Count[!Prefix!] += 1

    REM Rename the file using the prefix.
    CALL SET NewName=!Prefix!-%%Count[!Prefix!]%%
    REN "%%A" "!NewName!%%~xA"
)

ENDLOCAL
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solution which regards all of your requirements (see also `rem` comments):

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableExtensions

rem definition of temporary file:
set "TEMPFILE=%TMP%\~AlphaNum.tmp"

rem first loop structure for listing the files with `dir`
rem and creating the temporary file for later sorting:
> "%TEMPFILE%" (
    for /F "eol=| tokens=1,2,3,* delims=_" %%I in ('
        dir /B /A:-D "*_*_file*_*.ext"
    ') do (
        rem store different parts of the file name into variables:
        setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
        set "LINI=%%~I" & rem this is the very first part (prefix)
        set "LINL=%%~J" & rem this is the part left to `file*`
        set "LINM=%%~K" & rem this is the part `file*` (`*` is numeric)
        set "LINR=%%~L" & rem this is the part right to `file*`
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem extract the numeric part of `file*` and pad with leading `0`s;
        rem so the index is now of fixed width (12 figures at most here):
        set "LINN=000000000000!LINM:*file=!" & set "LINN=!LINN:~-12!"
        rem write file name with replaced fixed-width index and without
        rem word `file`, followed by `|`, followed by original file name,
        rem to the temporary file (the `echo` is redirected `>`):
        echo !LINI!_!LINL!_!LINN!_!LINR!^|!LINI!_!LINL!_!LINM!_!LINR!
        endlocal
        endlocal
    )
)

rem second loop structure for reading the temporary file,
rem sorting its lines with `sort`, generating new indexes
rem (sorting the previously built fixed-width indexes as text
rem result in the same order as sorting them as numbers) and
rem building the new file names (original first part + new index):
set "PREV="
for /F "eol=| tokens=2 delims=|" %%I in ('
    sort "%TEMPFILE%"
') do (
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    rem get the full original file name, and its extension:
    set "FILE=%%~I"
    set "FEXT=%%~xI"
    rem this loop iterates once only and extracts the part before the first `_`:
    for /F "eol=| tokens=1 delims=_" %%X in ("%%~I") do (
        set "CURR=%%~X"
    )
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem if the current prefix equals the previous one, increment the index;
    rem otherwise, reset the index to `1`:
    if /I "!CURR!"=="!PREV!" (
        set /A SNUM+=1
    ) else (
        set /A SNUM=1
    )
    rem remove `ECHO` from the following line to actually rename files:
    ECHO ren "!FILE!" "!CURR!-!SNUM!!FEXT!"
    rem this loop iterates once only and transports the values of
    rem some variable values past the `setlocal`/`endlocal` barrier:
    for /F "tokens=1,* delims=|" %%X in ("!SNUM!|"!CURR!"") do (
        endlocal
        endlocal
        set "SNUM=%%X"
        set "PREV=%%~Y"
    )
)

rem remove `REM` from the following line to delete temporary file:
REM del "%TEMPFILE%"

endlocal
```

The toggling of `EnableDelayedExpansion` and `DisableDelayedExpansion` is required to make the script robust for any special characters that might occur in file names, like `%`, `!`, `(`, `)`, `&` and `^`. Type `set /?` into the command prompt to find brief information about delayed variable expansion.

This approach relies on the following assumptions:

- the files match the pattern `*_*_file*_*.ext`;
- none of the file name parts `*` contain `_` characters on its own;
- the indexes after the word `file` are decimal numbers with up to 12 digits;
- the part between first and second `_` takes precedence over the index after the word `file` with respect to the sort order; so for instance, supposing there are two files `abc_AAA_file8_*.ext` and `abc_BBB_file5_*.ext`, `abc_AAA_file8_*.ext` will be renamed to `abc-1.ext` and `abc_BBB_file5_*.ext` to `abc-2.ext`, because `AAA` comes before `BBB`; if this is *not* the desired behaviour, exchange the `echo` command line in the first loop structure by this one:
  `echo !LINI!_!LINN!_!LINL!_!LINR!^|!LINI!_!LINL!_!LINM!_!LINR!`;
- the newly generated indexes are not padded with leading zeros;

With the sample files from your question, the temporary file contains the following lines:

> ```
> abc_foo_000000000001_morestuff.ext|abc_foo_file1_morestuff.ext
> abc_foo_000000000002_morestuff.ext|abc_foo_file2_morestuff.ext
> efg_goo_000000000001_morestuff.ext|efg_goo_file1_morestuff.ext
> jkl_zoo_000000000000_morestuff.ext|jkl_zoo_file0_morestuff.ext
> jkl_zoo_000000000001_morestuff.ext|jkl_zoo_file1_morestuff.ext
> jkl_zoo_000000000004_morestuff.ext|jkl_zoo_file4_morestuff.ext
> xyz_roo_000000000006_morestuff.ext|xyz_roo_file6_morestuff.ext
> ```

Comment: I got this working with great ease, thank you!  It will only let me select one accepted answer unfortunately and I have decided to go with the Python script since I was able to manipulate it fairly easily.  Your reply has been really helpful for me in learning some useful batch programming though, thanks so much.

Comment: You're welcome! that's true, only one answer can be accepted; however, you can upvote multiple helpful answers... ;-)

Comment: No worries, I did!  But my account is new so my votes apparently don't show up publicly until I have a higher rep score.